# How to return the calculated (aggregated) result of a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum, aggregate

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will return a number (an average) - this is what I have so far...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetAverageRating]
    @RecipeNodeId int 
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    (SELECT SUM(Rating) AS RatingTotal
     FROM dbo.RecipeRating
     WHERE RecipeNodeId = @RecipeNodeId)

    (SELECT 
         COUNT(Rating) AS RatingEntries 
     FROM dbo.RecipeRating 
     WHERE RecipeNodeId = @RecipeNodeId)
```

So this works and gives me

A.) Rating Total
B.) Number of Rating Entries

I want to return Rating Total / Rating Entries from the stored procedure.

Can anyone help me with the syntax please?

Comment: looks like you are trying to calculate average..`select avg(rating) from dbo.RecipeRating`? is that correct?

Comment: Didn't know there was an avg function....I do now :-) thanks

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the AVG function:

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) as RatingTotal
FROM dbo.RecipeRating
WHERE RecipeNodeId = @RecipeNodeId
```

Comment: Perhaps it would make more sense to put this in a UDF instead of a SPROC. `create function fnAvgRating(@RecipeNodeId int) returns decimal as select avg(Rating) from dbo.RecipeRating where RecipeNodeId = @RecipeNodeId`